# Efficient and fastest way to parse json python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a JSON content in the file and I need to iterate the JSON to take only the specific keys and its values.(values is another dictionary)

```
{"100": {"aaa": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}, 
         "bbb": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}, 
         "ccc": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}, 
         "ddd": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}
         ....
        },
"200": {"aaa": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}, 
        "bbb": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}, 
        "ccc": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}, 
        "ddd": {"Data": [10387], "Index": 90}
        ....
        },
   ....
   }
```

My inputs to the script as follows.List of Ids and Names. For example 
1. Ids =>[100,200] , name => ["aaa","bbb"] or 
   Ids => [100], ["aaa","bbb","ccc"] ....

I need to parse the JSON content and take only the Ids and names from the content and create another JSON.
My Codes as follows:

```
def read_json_file(self, json_filename):
        file_path = os.path.join(self.mock_file_dir, json_filename)
        with open(file_path) as file:
            content = file.read()
        return content
```

My First Approach ( dict comprehension). Input Ids=[100,200] , Names: ['aaa','bbb']

```
  content = json.loads(read_json_file(json_filename))
  ids_in_json = content.keys()

  result = {id: {name: content[str(id)][name]
                   for name in names} for id in Ids
                   if str(id ) in ids_in_json }

  return json.dumps(result)
```

Second Approach ( For Loop)

```
result = {}
  content = json.loads(read_json_file(json_pm_filename))
  ids_in_json = content.keys()

  for id in Ids:
    if str(id) in content.keys():
       for name in names:
          result[cell].update({name : content[str(id)][name]})

  return json.dumps(result)
```

Both gives almost the same performance. How can I do this very efficiently and faster way parse this.
Please help.

Comment: Have you looked into `import json`? It's part of the python standard libary and designed to do exactly what your trying. Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: @Elephant OP is already using that library.

Comment: @RoadRunner Oh yes, sorry my bad didn't read the second example closely enough

Comment: Are there alot of ids or is `Ids = [100,200]` just an example?

Comment: Yes. It's just an example. It is a list of numbers. It can go more than 10K also based on the input.

Comment: When testing performance, the first thing to do is: measure. Simple `print(time.time())` will suffice. For example, is the majority of the time being spent in the `for` loop or reading the file? If the file size is the problem, fixing the for loop will not help.

Comment: Use a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to see which parts of the program are taking the longest.

Comment: @RoadRunner Ya.I will check with profiler